# How can I close a tabItem that in a tabcontrolwrapper?

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

I am using the uia backend.  I am trying to close a tab item in a tab control wrapper.

I have the following elements:

- the tab control wrapper `a`:

```
<uia_controls.TabControlWrapper - 'Tab', TabControl, 3713040685325610831>
```

- the tab item `b`:

```
<uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Tab', TabItem, 13547299422468733>
```

The tab item `b` has a visual cross to close it from the UI, but when I call:

```
b.close()
```

It does not do the same thing, it basically does not close the tab.

I obviously tried the `close()` method which did not work as mentioned previously.

I also tried to right click on the tab using `click_input()` which makes the close tooltip appear but I did not investigate too much because of the limitation of this API.

Finally, when I do:

```
b.click_input(coords=(86,10))
```

It works, but it has two drawbacks:

- it uses click_input
- it uses hardcoded offsets

Has anyone a better solution?

Comment: Can it be reproduced on Notepad++ for example? Or maybe it's possible to download the target application?

Comment: Well, it seems Notepad++ tab item has no any child "Close" button. It's kind of owner-drawn area of the tab item itself. I think it's not possible to make method `.close()` working with it.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I came to the same conclusion as I was not able to find any object corresponding to the 'X' cross to close.  But since it was pretty widely used as a closable tab object, I thought it could be part of a lower layer implementation.

Comment: You can stick coordinates to top-right corner of the item with subtraction of `b.rectangle().top` and `b.rectangle().right` values against some fixed offsets.